# How to use same service account JSON key between two Google Actions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

Background: We have two Google Actions - they both use the same fulfillment URL (same API). The only differences between the two are the name, icons, and descriptions associated with each action. The first action was certified by Google, and we saved the JSON key that we use for report state to our Azure KeyVault.

Now we are attempting to get our second action certified, but we are facing an issue where we need to add the same key to our second service account associated with the new action, since this is the key we have saved in our KeyVault. I see you can upload a public key to a service account, but I am not sure how to use the previous JSON key we generated for the first action. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were are deployed y our fullfilment API?

Comment: They are hosted on our Azure account.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by creating two separate Google Clients in our code Azure function. Each client represents one of the Actions and respective HomeGraph API keys. This seems to be working fine, and we are able to send StateReports and ReportSync to Google successfully.